# JUNIT - Testing the sequence of methods

Tags: junit

I have a following simple JAVA program called SequenceExample that executes three methods in sequence :

1. Washing()
2. Drying ()
3. Folding ()

I want to write a JUNIT test that ensures that this sequence is maintained. In other words in future if the code is changed to  execute `Drying()` before `Washing()` then my JUNIT should fail and give a message that "Laundry Sequence is not in order"

Please let me know if you have any idea how to achieve this.
Thanks,
Dayanand.

```
public class SequenceExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         //Shows Sequential Steps for laundry

         Washing();  //Sequence#1
         Drying();   //Sequence#2
         Folding();  //Sequence#3
    }

    private static void Washing(){
        System.out.println("Washing - This is Step One of Laundry");
    }

    private static void Drying(){
        System.out.println("Drying  - This is Step Two of Laundry");
    }

    private static void Folding(){
        System.out.println("Folding - This is Step Three of Laundry");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this check should be performed in the code. Otherwise the code client could allow a not acceptable sequence.
In the unit test you could check that the `SequenceExample` class behaviors as expected :

- if the sequence is valid, no exception is risen.
- if the sequence is not valid, an exception prevents the client code from going on.

Some hints :

1) You nest many things in `SequenceExample` and doesn't use instance of `SequenceExample`. You should favor instances and instance methods if you don't write utility methods.

2) Method names should be verb in the infinitive form (conventions) : **wash**, **dry** and **fold** and not washing, drying and folding.

3) Each method has a specific behavior and should be callable from a client code. Making them private doesn't seem desirable.

4) You could introduce a field  in `SequenceExample`  that maintains the current state. A Java enum could do the job. 
Each method could check the state before performing its task and throwing an exception if the state is not which one expected.
And at the end of the method the state will be modified.

Here is a modified version of your class :

```
public class SequenceExample {

    public enum State {
        WASHING, DRYING, FOLDING,
    }

    private State state;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Shows Sequential Steps for laundry
        SequenceExample sequenceExample = new SequenceExample();
        sequenceExample.wash(); // Sequence#1
        sequenceExample.dry(); // Sequence#2
        sequenceExample.fold(); // Sequence#3
    }

    public void wash() {
        if (state != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("state should be null");
        }
        System.out.println("Washing - This is Step One of Laundry");
        state = State.WASHING;
    }

    public void dry() {
        if (state != State.WASHING) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("state should be WASHING");
        }
        System.out.println("Drying  - This is Step Two of Laundry");
        state = State.DRYING;
    }

    public void fold() {
        if (state != State.DRYING) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("state should be WASHING");
        }
        System.out.println("Folding - This is Step Three of Laundry");
        state = State.FOLDING;
    }
}
```

Here is a test class with a test that invokes the methods in the good order and
3 tests that don't and so wait for an exception rising.

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class SequenceExampleTest {

    SequenceExample sequenceExample = new SequenceExample();

    @Test
    public void sequenceCorrect() throws Exception {
        sequenceExample.wash();
        sequenceExample.dry();
        sequenceExample.fold();
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void sequenceNotCorrectCaseOne() throws Exception {
        sequenceExample.dry();
        sequenceExample.wash();
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void sequenceNotCorrectCaseTwo() throws Exception {
        sequenceExample.dry();
        sequenceExample.fold();
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void sequenceNotCorrectCasethree() throws Exception {
        sequenceExample.wash();
        sequenceExample.fold();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) to spy on your test subject and verify the methods were called in the expected order.

```
@Test
public void laundry() {

    // given
    Laundry subject = spy(new Laundry());

    // when
    subject.wash();
    subject.dry();
    subject.fold();

    // then
    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(subject);
    inOrder.verify(subject).wash();
    inOrder.verify(subject).dry();
    inOrder.verify(subject).fold();
}
```

If for some reason, a future developer thinks it's a wise idea to fold wet laundry, then the test will fail with the following signal:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure: 
Verification in order failure
Wanted but not invoked:
laundry.fold();
-> at LaundryTest.laundry(LaundryTest.java:24)
Wanted anywhere AFTER following interaction:
laundry.dry();
-> at LaundryTest.laundry(LaundryTest.java:18)
```